# Trying to implement a custom iterator that works seamlessly with iterator functions like for filter map flatmap etc

Tags: rust

Can someone please, understand what I am doing here, and suggest me the right way to do this, honestly I have no idea what I am doing.

```
struct SqIterator<I>(I);

impl<I> Iterator for SqIterator<I>
  where I: Iterator<Item = Square>, {
  type Item  = I::Item;

  fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
    self.0.next()
  }
}

impl<I: Iterator<Item = Square> + Clone> SqIterator<I> {

  fn new(iter: I) -> Self {
    SqIterator(iter)
  }

  fn into_a_pd(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (Square, BitboardPD)> {
    self.0.clone().flat_map(|a| Waypoint::a_square(a)
    .into_iter().map(move |pd| (a, pd)))
  }
}

struct Sq2<T>(SqIterator<T>, SqIterator<T>);


struct Dasher;

impl Dasher {
  /* P_k!!W */
  fn no_dash<'a, T: Iterator<Item = Square> + Clone>(bs: &'a Bs, a: &'a SqIterator<T>, b: &'a SqIterator<T>) -> Sq2<T> {
    todo!()
  }

  fn dash<'a, T: Iterator<Item = Square> + Clone>(bs: &'a Bs, a: &'a SqIterator<T>, b: &'a SqIterator<T>) -> impl Iterator<Item = Sq2<T>> {
    a.into_a_pd().map(|(a, pd)| {
      let aa = SqIterator([a].iter());
      let bb = b.filter(|&b| pd.dest.into() == b.pos);
      Sq2(aa, bb)
    })
  }
}
```

Here's the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/gg.rs:106:15
    |
105 |       let bb = b.filter(|&b| pd.dest.into() == b.pos);
    |                         ---- the found closure
106 |       Sq2(aa, bb)
    |       ---     ^^ expected `SqIterator<Iter<'_, Square>>`, found `Filter<SqIterator<T>, ...>`
    |       |
    |       arguments to this struct are incorrect
    |
    = note: expected struct `SqIterator<std::slice::Iter<'_, bitboard::Square>>`
               found struct `Filter<SqIterator<T>, [closure@src/gg.rs:105:25: 105:29]>`
note: tuple struct defined here
   --> src/gg.rs:91:8
    |
91  | struct Sq2<T>(SqIterator<T>, SqIterator<T>);
```

Here' are some more delicateness for completion:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Square {
    pos: u32,
    piece: u32
}

struct BitboardPD {
  path: u32,
  dest: u32
}

struct Bs;

struct Waypoint;

impl Waypoint {
    fn a_square(a: Square) -> Vec<BitboardPD> {
        vec![]
    }
}
```

Comment: @cafce25 MRE https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cb3e2b27fefee1f1c8f025d6072a9da9

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that (all?) iterator adapters return a *different* type from the one you start with. So you'll have to deal with different iterators in your code as well.
Your code has several other issues, but to get you started don't reuse the same generic type parameter so often. [Rustlings traits4.rs Why impl Trait syntax works but trait bound syntax or where clause does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73319281/rustlings-traits4-rs-why-impl-trait-syntax-works-but-trait-bound-syntax-or-where?noredirect=1&lq=1) has some explanation why that's bad.

For example the definition of `Sq2` should most definitely be

```rust
struct Sq2<T, U>(SqIterator<T>, SqIterator<U>);
```

similarly `no_dash` should take more parameters:

```rust
fn no_dash<'a, T, U>(bs: &'a Bs, a: &'a SqIterator<T>, b: &'a SqIterator<U>) -> Sq2<T, U>
where
    T: Iterator<Item = Square> + Clone,
    U: Iterator<Item = Square> + Clone,
{
    todo!()
}
```

when you're implementing `dash` you can't name all the implementations so you'll have to resort to some replaced by `impl Iterator<Item = Square> + Clone` or similar:

```rust
fn dash<'a, T, U>(
    bs: &'a Bs,
    a: &'a SqIterator<T>,
    b: &'a SqIterator<U>,
) -> impl Iterator<Item = Sq2<impl Iterator<Item = Square>, impl Iterator<Item = Square>>>
where
    T: Iterator<Item = Square> + Clone,
    U: Iterator<Item = Square> + Clone,
{
    a.into_a_pd().map(|(a, pd)| {
        let aa = SqIterator([a].iter());
        let bb = SqIterator(b.filter(|&b| pd.dest.into() == b.pos));
        Sq2(aa, bb)
    })
}
```

There are still some lifetime issues with the code, but they are not directly related to the initial question, but were just hidden by those errors.

Comment: this doesn't remotely address the problem, i am sticking to vectors now.

Comment: Honestly there isn't [too much more to edit](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1a5ca83250f2037751dbec3645652773) but yea the original code was tough to work with.